# Flutter hintStyle copy

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[i want to build a textfield like this image i uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfltr.png)
I wanna change a property on Textfield without touching source file.
Its in input_decorator.dart

```
final Widget? hint = decoration!.hintText == null ? null : AnimatedOpacity(
      opacity: (isEmpty && !_hasInlineLabel) ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      duration: _kTransitionDuration,
      curve: _kTransitionCurve,
      alwaysIncludeSemantics: true,
      child: Text(
        decoration!.hintText!,
        style: hintStyle,
        textDirection: decoration!.hintTextDirection,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        textAlign: textAlign,
        maxLines: decoration!.hintMaxLines,
      ),
    );
```

I just wanna remove that opacity but not in source file

Comment: As you have the return as a widget and you have a condition stating that if the hint style is null use the default one, you can pass the widget to decoration.hintstype  animatedOpacity as parent and make it 0.

Comment: you didnt understand,that code is here: \flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\input_decorator.dart . so i dont wanna change that. i would use a method like copywith create a clone and change cloned object

Comment: Can you send me the UI that you have and the one that you are expecting.

Comment: a textfield with auto complete on hint.